# Slides Jquery plugin - similar to BBC Beta

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, slide

Have you guys seen the new BBC homepage? Check it out.. http://beta.bbc.co.uk/

I love the slide thing, which jQuery Plugin can do this?

Comment: fwiw; that page probably uses the BBC's js lib 'Glow': http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [SlideJS](http://slidesjs.com/) is a good start, you'll have to style / extend it to your needs.

Comment: I have tried SlideJS, I am having problem displaying previous div. It hide automatically.